# What does the "Auto Sign-in" feature in Google Chrome do?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Google chrome `Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)` on Ubuntu, when I go to settings (accessible via the url: `chrome://settings` or by clicking on <kbd>settings</kbd> in the options menu, then click on:

[image]

this launches this  window revealing the `Auto Sign-in` option:

[image]

I thought might mean what it says and - "Auto-matically log me in" - so I have tried logging into a few websites, logging out and visiting the "sign in" url again, expecting that it would log me in automatically, it didn't.

Then I thought it might have something to do with pre-populating login fields with login credentials which chrome saved from previous logins, but that pre-form filling behaviour seems to occur automatically when you chose <kbd>Save</kbd> rather than <kbd>never</kbd> when chrome prompts to save your password.

What does chrome's "Auto Sign-in" option actually do?

Comment: It means it fills in the fields then submits the data.  You have to use chrome to manage your passwords for this to work obviously

Comment: @Ramhound, it didn't do that for me. do you know what triggers it? do I need to simply click the `login` link for the website - and it will then auto sign-in, or is there another step?

Comment: I have the settings as per the screen shots I posted, so chrome is handling my passwords. I have then tried restarting chrome. and repeated this on 3 different websites. including superuser.com - the form fields get filled out - but this occurs even when auto-sign in is off (but offer to save webpasswords is on, and I choose SAVE). otherwise checking the `Auto signin` seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 15):

The labels are pretty [misleading](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=822465#c2). It's not a regular auto-login option but a new login flow which is manipulated by `Credential Management` and is not being used widely yet. For more information, see Google's [The Credential Management API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/) or the official paper by [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/credential-management/).

However, you can still test the functionality using a [demo](https://credential-management-sample.appspot.com/) provided by Google itself. Before navigating to the demo URL, you have to enable both `Offer to save passwords` (so your credential can be saved and used later) and `Auto Sign-in` (to actually enable the feature) options in Password settings (`chrome://settings/passwords`):
[image]

Then go to [Credential Management API Demo](https://credential-management-sample.appspot.com/) (or any other site manipulates Credential Manager Javascript API). Sign up with a fake email and save it:
[image]

Now whenever you click on `SIGN IN` button, a popup will be shown like this so you can log into your account with a single click/tap:

[image]

However, if you need a auto-login feature for regular websites, I recommend LastPass [extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass-free-password-ma/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd) and its application for phones.